Recent MSVC versions don't treat NAN as constant, workaround?
Recent MSVC versions don't seem to treat NAN as a constant anymore. The new definition appears to be (__ucrt_int_to_float(0x7FC00000)). The old one was (-(float)(((float)(1e+300 * 1e+300)) * 0.0F)).
This causes code like the following to fail to compile with error C2099: initializer is not a constant:
#include <math.h>

double x[] = { 1.0, NAN };

Unfortunately, I don't have direct access to MSVC and I am dealing with this through GitHub CI.
Questions:

Is this a bug in MSVC or valid behaviour?
What is a robust workaround that won't break the code with other compilers?

Apparently, MSVC also doesn't accept 0.0 / 0.0. The code double f() { return 0.0 / 0.0; } fails with error C2124: divide or mod by zero

GodBolt appears to have no problem with x64 MSVC v19 latest: https://godbolt.org/z/obbsb6znn

I know, it doesn't have the latest MSVC. It seems this affects 17.12, but not 17.11. Godbolt has 17.10.

Found some discussion: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/17308  and  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/NAN-is-no-longer-compile-time-constant-i/10688907

NAN must be a constant expression. If it isn't, then that's a compiler/library bug.

Related question I just posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/79195163/695132

it compiles without any problems https://godbolt.org/z/s864rqPjb

@0___________ It does not compile with recent MSVC versions, please read the comments above.

Also, this is obviously not a duplicate. The question is entirely different. Please don't abuse closing powers. This is exactly why StackOverflow is getting such a bad reputation recently.

@Szabolcs it does. VS17.12 MSVC Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.42.34433 for x86. Tested on my computer

This is a bug in MSVC.
The NAN macro is required to be a constant expression.  Such expressions are allowed in file scope initializers as they can be evaluated at compile time.
This is mandated in section 7.12p6 of the C99 standard:

The macro
NAN

is defined if and only if the implementation supports quiet NaNs for
the float type. It expands to a constant expression of type float
representing a quiet NaN.

The same language exists in C11 and C23.
This it's the first time that MSVC has exhibited non standard compliant behavior.
To work around this, you can check the MSVC version by inspecting the _MSC_VER macro.  For MSVC 17.12, the internal version number is 19.42 which translates to a macro value of 1942.  Based on this, you can redefine NAN to what is was previously.
#include <math.h>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
# if _MSC_VER >= 1942
#   undef NAN
#   define NAN (-(float)(((float)(1e+300 * 1e+300)) * 0.0F))
# endif
#endif


MSVC is a C++ compiler, not a C compiler.  I don't think it makes any claims to be C compliant.

@MarkRansom: It's marketed as a "C/C++ compiler" and there's an entire documentation section on using it for C.  There's also a specific option for C11/C17 compliance.

@NateEldredge thanks for the link, I wasn't aware they were even making an effort.  This site is littered with examples of MSVC not conforming 100% to C standards.

@MarkRansom This is from memory, so details might be wrong, but I think before VS 2015 they didn't make any improvements to C that wasn't needed for C++, and there was little to no support for C99. I remember having a lot of workarounds in igraph. VS 2015 made major improvements. It doesn't have full language support, but the standard library is in a very good shape. After that, it's quite shocking to see this NAN messup.
